# MPI_Barrier() gets blocked at the beggining

Tags: mpi

I'm trying to synchronize my processes at the beginning of the execution via MPI_Barrier but my program gets blocked on it. Nevertheless, I see all the processes are reaching that line by printing on the screen in the previous instruction.

```
    int num_processes, packet_size, partner_rank; 
    double start_comm_time, end_comm_time, comm_time;
    comm_time = 0;
    if(argc==3) { 
        if (sscanf (argv[1], "%i", &num_processes) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error - parameter 1 not an integer");
        } else;
        if (sscanf (argv[2], "%i", &packet_size) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error - parameter 2 not an integer");
        } else;
     }
    else {
            printf("\n Usage: broadcast $count $packet_size");
            return 0; 
    }

    char buf_send[packet_size], buf_recv[packet_size];
    buf_send[0] = 0;

    // Initialize
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    int world_rank;

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
    int world_size;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

    printf("\n Comm size %d \n", world_size);
    printf("\n Process %d before barrier \n", world_rank);
    // Time MPI_Bcast
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    printf("\n Process %d after barrier \n", world_rank);
    start_comm_time = MPI_Wtime();
    MPI_Bcast(buf_send, packet_size, MPI_CHAR, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    printf("\n Process %d before second barrier \n", world_rank);
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    end_comm_time = MPI_Wtime();
```

This is what I get in the printout:

```
 Comm size 6 

 Process 0 before barrier 

 Comm size 6 

 Process 2 before barrier 

 Comm size 6 

 Process 3 before barrier 
 Comm size 6 

 Process 1 before barrier 

 Comm size 6 

 Process 4 before barrier 

 Comm size 6 

 Process 5 before barrier
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your program.  The culprit is probably your mpi installation.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the timing and `MPI_Bcast` parts of your program (because it is incomplete), and it runs well on my machine, without getting blocked. So there could be something wrong with other parts of your code.

According to your whole program, I don't think your code has some problems. The problem is probably your mpi environment. I also run it on my machine using `mpirun -n 6 ./xxx 6 1`, and this is what I get:

```
 Comm size 6 

 Process 0 before barrier 

 Comm size 6 

 Process 5 before barrier 

 Comm size 6 

 Process 2 before barrier 

 Comm size 6 

 Comm size 6 

 Process 1 before barrier 

 Process 3 before barrier 

 Comm size 6 

 Process 4 before barrier 

 Process 0 after barrier 

 Process 0 before second barrier 

 Process 1 after barrier 

 Process 1 before second barrier 

 Process 4 after barrier 

 Process 4 before second barrier 

 Process 5 after barrier 

 Process 5 before second barrier 

 Process 2 after barrier 

 Process 2 before second barrier 

 Process 3 after barrier 

 Process 3 before second barrier
```

Comment: Thanks for trying it. I don't think it's due to the other part of the code because as shown in the output, the sentence previous to the Barrier is executed for all the processes, but if you don mind to try it out, I'm adding the initialization part to the code:

Comment: I have updated my answer with my output. I don't think there is something wrong with your code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I gonna check my environment again.